# Will Microsoft HoloLens work with Visual Studio as 'virtual' multi monitor display?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, visual-studio

I like working with a laptop for portability.
But during development I like to have many windows / displays.

I was wondering if I could use a Microsoft Hololens to give me some more 'screen' real-estate.

*However I have heard that Hololens can only work with some types of apps, and I am unsure if Visual Studio is one of them.*

Googling doesn't help much as the results only talk about how to use visual studio to develop **for** HoloLens not developing with visual studio **on** HoloLens.

**Would it be possible to have the various undocked tabs from visual studio show up as mixed reality virtual objects in a HoloLens display?**

Comment: IF this is the case, it will be documented in some way by Microsoft. Either any application can be inserted into a HoloLens display, in which case the answer would be "yes", or you need apps, in which case the answer would be "it depends".

Comment: @music2myear Or someone with a HoloLens could spin up VS, pull a tab off and see if they can put it into their HoloLens field of view. Then they would be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: A) that presumes someone here has a HoloLens, or B) it assumes this is where Microsoft does their support. You may find a better answer (and more quickly too) by posting this in an official Microsoft support forum where HoloLens staff could provide an official answer.

Comment: [Looks like VS Code may not be supported but you can use a web browser and some simple IDE's](https://www.slashgear.com/hololens-daily-shows-how-to-do-multi-screens-in-style-19456514/)

Answer (score 1):

While I was unable to find an explicit statement confirming or denying the ability for VS to run in HoloLens, the evidence indicates this is not the case, and further indicates that HoloLens is NOT designed to replace static computer displays. This article describes HoloLens support for Microsoft Office, arguably much higher in the ToDo list for HoloLens support, and the native Office programs do not run in HoloLens: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-on-hololens-faq-fb759498-080e-400e-bffb-56b2fb4c3246

Here is the link to the MS Store for ALL HoloLens apps: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/collections/hlgettingstarted/hololens

If there are log viewers for HoloLens, they'd be in here.